# how to write the script in jmeter to fill and edit the data dynamically for the fields in the site?

Tags: java, validation, automation, jmeter

In the site i have a fields like productName, productDescription, productId, Quantity. I need to write the script for the fields in jmeter. It has to the ability to write and edit the data automatically at the time of testing. Need solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

Explored for solution didn't find anywhere need help to sort it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't "fill" or "edit" any "fields", it sends [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) with the specified payload, waits for the response and measures the time in-between.

So you need to come up with a relevant HTTP Request definition by:

1. Either building it manually populating relevant fields of the [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Or recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

One you have request "skeleton" with recorded hard-coded values you can [variabilize](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) it, for example change the values in that way JMeter would read it from i.e. CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each virtual user would use new set of values on each iteration